# Is `[](std::list<int>& list){return std::move(list)}(list)` guaranteed to leave `list` empty?

Tags: c++, c++14, move, move-semantics

More particularly:

```
struct A{
    std::list<int> list;
    std::list<int> foo(){
        return std::move(list);
    }
}

A a;
// insert some elements into a.list
a.foo(); // is this guaranteed to clear a.list?
```

Is the last line above guaranteed to leave `a.list` empty?

Comment: You mentioned std::move(). Are you planning to entertain return value or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Moving from most standard library classes leaves them in a "valid but unspecified state" [1]. That means you have to explicitly clear `a.list` in order to ensure that it's empty after the move.

[1] There are exceptions to this rule: most notably, `std::unique_ptr` is required to be null after a move.

Comment: So `std::vector` and `std::list` are not among those exceptions?

Comment: @Museful Right. I don't think any of the standard containers guarantee a particular state after a move, other than `std::array` since its move constructor is the implicit one.

Comment: @Museful to be sure they are empty just do `list = {}` after moving it.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Yes but that requires two additional lines of code if the list is being returned from a function, or is there another way?

Comment: @Museful `return std::exchange(list, {});`

Comment: What do you think about copy elision @Brian?

Answer (score 1):

> Is the last line above guaranteed to leave a.list empty?

No. The standard says following:

> [lib.types.movedfrom]
>
> Objects of types defined in the C++ standard library may be moved from ([class.copy.ctor]).
> Move operations may be explicitly specified or implicitly generated.
> Unless otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall be placed in a valid but unspecified state.

And this is the definition of *valid but unspecified state*:

> [defns.valid]
>
> value of an object that is not specified except that the object's invariants are met and operations on the object behave as specified for its type
>
> [ Example: If an object x of type std​::​vector is in a valid but unspecified state, x.empty() can be called unconditionally, and x.front() can be called only if x.empty() returns false.
> — end example ]

`std::list` specification adds no further guarantees for the move constructor.

Answer (score 0):

No, you must clear it otherwise it is left in an "unspecified state" - as per the documentation on `std::list`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is worth explaining why list might not be empty afterward.

If the move ends up being a copy, for example because of incompatible allocators and the allocator is not moved, then the list may still have the old elements.

Although vector is (inconsistently) required to be cleared in all cases, there is support in the Committee for requiring that the capacity of the assigned-to vector be moved back to the right-side operand when that would be compatible with the allocator situation.

Comment: However, notice that `std::list<int>` cannot possibly have "incompatible allocators." Even if you changed OP's code to use `std::pmr::list<int>`, this code would still be fine, because there's no possible way for a _move-construction_ (out of `this->list`, into the return slot) to involve "incompatible allocators" — there is only one allocator involved. The short answer is "yes, `a.list` must become empty (because there is physically no way for it to have any elements in it after the move has succeeded)."

Comment: Regarding "the capacity of the assigned-to vector be moved back to the right-side operand": YES, that is pragmatic and makes total sense, and allows people to finally see the use case of that "valid but unspecified" state moved from objects are to be left in. You can now check .capacity() and have a nice surprise: you have allocated memory ready to be used, and you didn't even need to ask for it!